# How to delete a particular div from html using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have some html and I want to remove a particular div tag with content using preg_replace.

Code:

```
<div class="time-trainer"> sjdgj</div>
```

I want to remove the div that have `class="time-trainer"` and remove the content as well.

preg_replace is working fine to remove image tag from html but how we can do same with div

```
$rmvimgfromdata = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "",  $data);
```

above code is working fine to remove image tage from html.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$html   = '<div class="time-trainer">Remove</div>';

// Show
echo $html;

// Remove
echo preg_replace('~<div([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']time-trainer["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</div>~i', '', $html);
```

**UPDATE**

Use DOM

```
$html   = '<div class="time-trainer">
                <p class="fifths">asdasdas</p>
                <p class="hundredths">asdasdas</p>
                <p class="winner-info">asdasdas</p>
            </div>';


$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='time-trainer']");

foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
  $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
}

echo preg_replace( "/.*<body>(.*)<\/body>.*/s", "$1", $dom->saveHTML() );
```

Comment: thanks for reply but itsa not working you can view the source of page here http://www.computerhorse.com/admin1/fetch.php  it still showing that div tag in html

Comment: if I am trying to use DOM its showing me warning as well functionality not work .Tell me if need to add any other file to enable DOM

Comment: There are no such tags in the document (computerhorse.com/admin1/fetch.php).

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements (and ensuring that the result is a valid xml) is not possible with preg_replace.

Consider the following example:

```
dsadsa
<div class="time-trainer">
  adsadas
  <div>dsadas</div>
  dsa
  <div>das</div>
  dsadsa
</div>
ddsadas
```

Regular expressions describe regular languages (L3) in language theory, and XML's are at a higher level (L1).

To modify XML files, you should use an xml parser, and delete / add / modify elements with that. Read the documentation about [XML manipulation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php)

Comment: No, PHP's PCRE regex library supports matching nested structures and can easily match the "impossible" example you cite (so does .NET and Perl. Please stop saying that regular expressions are REGULAR, They're not and haven't been for a long, long time. It may be true that there are more reliable methods to extract a DIV structure (e.g. XML DOM), but to say that it is _impossible_ to achieve using regex is simply false.